# Learning SQL, grabbing most recent configuration

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables:

```
-Parts-
ID
name

-ReportA-
ID
PART_ID
LOCATION_ID
GPS_ID
USER_ID
VALVE_ID
DATE

-ReportB-
ID
PART_ID
LOCATION_ID
TYPE_ID
NOTES
GPS_ID
DATE
```

(1) I would like to grab all parts that have either a Report A or B:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    parts
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT id FROM reports_a UNION SELECT id FROM reports_b
```

Perfect (1) But now I need to grab the LOCATION_ID and GPS_ID from the most recent Report (being either A or B).

Example:

```
-Parts-
1
Valve

-ReportA-
1
1
4
9
2
12
2013-02-01

-ReportB-
1
1
113
3
"Changed part"
90
2013-03-27
```

So I need an SQL script that can grab all parts and their latest location and gps id, the above result would yield:

```
PART_ID = 1
LOCATION_ID = 113
GPS_ID = 90
```

So I alter my SQL script from earlier to:

```
SELECT
    id AS PART_ID
    (
        (
           SELECT location_id FROM reports_a ORDER BY date DESC
           UNION
           SELECT location_id FROM reports_b ORDER BY date DESC
        )
        ORDER BY
           date DESC
        LIMIT 1  
    ) AS LOCATION_ID
FROM
    parts
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT id FROM reports_a UNION SELECT id FROM reports_b
```

However, I cannot order by date DESC because it is not a field returned by the UNION?

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I seemed misread the question earlier, the below query gets the latest data for a particular `product_id`

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
    (
      SELECT 
        CONCAT( 'Location_id: ',location_id, ' gps_id: ', gps_id, ' date: ', `date` )
      FROM 
        ( SELECT `date`,part_id, location_id, gps_id FROM reportA
        UNION 
        SELECT `date`,part_id, location_id, gps_id FROM reportB
        ) t
      WHERE part_id = p.id  
      ORDER BY `date` desc 
      LIMIT 1) 
    as details
FROM 
    parts p
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02b80/1)**

The structure used by you is not right, ideally you should have all your report_data within a single table with a column as `report_type` which could be `A` or `B`

Comment: How does this ensure that the JOIN gets the latest records from reportA and reportB?

Comment: @user2233440 I have updated the answer, you would need to wrap the results of the `union` as a subquery